# already initialized constant Bundler::Dsl::RAILS_VERSION_IS_3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, redmine, redmine-plugins

type `rails -v`  in a rails project (redmine 2.3)

the terminal logs :

`(eval):9: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::Dsl::RAILS_VERSION_IS_3
(eval):9: warning: previous definition of RAILS_VERSION_IS_3 was here
Rails 3.2.13`

type `bundle update`

the terminal:

```

```
Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.
Your Gemfile lists the gem thin (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem redcarpet (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
(eval):9: warning: already initialized constant Bundler::Dsl::RAILS_VERSION_IS_3
```

(eval):9: warning: previous definition of RAILS_VERSION_IS_3 was here

```

RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_backlogs VERSION=0

with the same error log.

i don't know how to solve.

environment:
ruby2.0,rails3.2,rvm1.26.11,Bundler version 1.9.9

Comment: you should keep only one `thin gem`.Delete the duplicate one in your gemfile.

Comment: can you show your Gemfile?

Comment: there are a Gemfile and a Gemfile.lock in the project root directory. the Gemfile has too many lines to show.i can just show part of it

Answer (score 0):

```
  remote: http://ruby.taobao.org/
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    ZenTest (4.5.0)
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
```